# Function for counting composite numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

I am analyzing the Goldbach conjecture for prime numbers, which states that every even number is a sum of two prime numbers.

I have a question about counting of composite numbers. Is there any known function to count couples of composite numbers?

I am interesting in counting of how many composite couples fulfill:
$$\text{composite}_1+\text{composite}_2=2^n$$

For example, $64 = 3*3+5*11 = 3*5+7*7 = 5*5+3*13$ ,there are three couples and $f(64)=3$.

For $32$ there are no composite sums couples so $f(32)=0$.

For $128 = 3*3*7+5*13 = 3*17+7*11 = 5*7+3*31 = 3*11+5*19 = 3*3+7*17$ there are $5$ couples so $f(128)=5$

Function itself may be approximate, similar as the prime number counting function $x/ln(x)$.

The function should not count composite couples of $2$, because this can be counted by $(2^n/4)-1$.

Such function may lead to a proof of the Goldbach conjecture for prime sums equals to $2^n$ and maybe even a proof of the whole Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: Even if such a counting function is known, we have to consider the case $2n=p+c$, where $p$ is prime and $c$ is composite. Such tools will not proof Goldbach, I think.

Comment: Articles, man. Use those *the*'s and *a*'s, your english will become so much easier to understand ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = 2^n$ for convenience.

There are $x/4$ ways to write $x$ as a sum of two odd numbers.  Of these, $\pi(x/2)$ have a prime (or $1$) in the first (lesser) component, and $\pi(x) - \pi(x/2)$ have a prime in the second (greater) component.  Therefore the number of pairs of odd composite numbers summing to $x$ is bounded below by
$$x/4 - \pi(x) \sim x/4$$
and bounded above by
$$x/4 - \pi(x/2) \sim x/4,$$
so it is clearly asymptotic to $x/4$ with an error term of size $\Theta(x/\log x)$.  The relative error in this approximation is $\Theta(1/\log x)$, exactly the same order of accuracy as $\pi(x) \approx x/\log x$ which has an error of size $\Theta(x/\log^2 x)$.

Addendum: for an even better approximation, one can prove via sieve methods that the number of prime pairs summing to $x$ is bounded above by $O(x/\log^2 x)$ (note the constant here depends on the prime divisors of $x$, so we are making critical use of the fact that $x = 2^n$).  Therefore, the intersection of the two sets of sums in the above paragraph is asymptotically small, and so $x/4 - x/\log x$ is an approximation that is accurate to within a relative error of $O(1/\log^2 x)$.  Probably no further asymptotic terms can be extracted, except heuristically: the dependence on Goldbach's conjecture is pretty clear.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have checked that for x=4096 there are 513 composite couples, while 4096/4=1024. The relative error is (1024-513)/513 = 0.99 and approximation of relative error is O(1/log(x))=0.12, the error is much bigger than expected approximation.  For 2^20 there are 184358 couples and 2^20/4=262144. Relative error is 0.42 and approximation O(1/logx) is 0.072, the error is bigger than expectation. I think that this approximation has too big error. Do you think that for large n, the approximation will be closer to exact results?

Comment: @IvanSas For large $n$ the relative error shrinks to $0$: that is what asymptotic means, but with a relative error of $O(1/\log x)$ it takes a long time to do so.  If you want a more accurate approximation on average, then the lower bound is likely closer to the truth most of the time.  See edit.

Comment: @IvanSas $0.99$ is only $8$ times larger than $0.12$: why do you say it is bigger than expectation?  $10/\log n$ is still $O(1/\log n)$.

Comment: @IvanSas My point here is that what you are counting is essentially equivalent in difficulty to counting pairs of primes (up to error terms in PNT which can be made quite small).  However, you are studying a quantity of size $x/4$ when the Goldbach problem is sensitive to "minute" errors of size $x/\log^2 x$, so it's a very ham-fisted approach that doesn't appear to yield any new insights.

Comment: @EricWong Thank you for your help. So I understand that this approximation can't  be used in proof. Do you think that if there will be exact function to compute count of sums of odd numbers, or at least much better function with less error than it will be possible to proof Goldbach conjecture?

Comment: @IvanSas If a precise estimate for your count was available with an error of less than $o(x/\log^2 x)$ was available, then one could prove Goldbach's conjecture for the extremely limited case where $x$ is a power of $2$.  But this is utterly trivial since (# of odd composite pairs) is just $x/4 - \pi(x) +$ (# of prime pairs), give or take a constant.  The function you're asking about is almost exactly the same as the one in Goldbach's conjecture.  There's nothing new to be gained this way, because the $x/4$ and $\pi(x)$ are well-understood, and all the difficulty lies in the prime term.